# It is on Tuesday at 10:30AM. vs It is at 10:30AM on Tuesday

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice, word-meaning

A question about time order. Which one is more natural?

> 1) It is Tuesday at 10:30AM.
>   2) It is at 10:30AM on Tuesday.

I thought #2 is the correct one, but I received an e-mail like #1 from a native, saying I will meet you on Tuesday, August 15th at 10:30 AM.

Comment: 1) as written is just telling the date and time. I presume you are trying to state the date and time of some event. In that case, you need "1) It is *on* Tuesday at 10:30AM." This one and 2) would carry the same meaning

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly fine, grammatically, but stylistically, I (a native speaker, Boston, USA) personally prefer to use #1 when discussing scheduling (which I do *a lot*).  I have the belief – though I can't substantiate it – that stating the day first reduces right-time-wrong-day errors.  I never want the time to be more salient to the reader than the date, since whether entering the appointment into a paper datebook or a digital calendar, first one has to navigate to the right day, and then find the time block.  So I state the date first, and then the time.

Answer (score 1):

Though there's nothing wrong with the sentence #2 grammatically, it's far more common and idiomatic that the day precedes the time.  So the sentence #1 is appropriate and preferable.